# how to recover credentials of cartridge installation?

Tags: openshift, jbpm

is possible to recover the credentials generated during installation? In particular  jboss bpm suite' s console and dashboard.
It happens that the creation last longer and i need to refresh the page for this reason i can't get the green frame with all details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have rhc command-line installed, then you can simply do

```
rhc ssh --app <app_name> --command 'env'
```

Answer (score 0):

Get to your application console page (through the openshift web ui), grab the ssh connection link (Remote Access) and use it to get a terminal connection open in your application space.

Then type "env" and you should see a bunch of environnement variables, your credentials should be stored in one of them.